# What is the probability that the hotel will not have enough space for the guests?

Tags: probability

**A hotel accepted reservations from 1150 people, but it has capacity for only 1000 guests. If the probability that a guest will cancel the reservation is 0.1, what is the probability that the hotel will not have enough place for all of the guests?**

Hi,

I tried to solve this problem, but i am afraid that i am making some mistakes. Can you please check if i am making some mistakes and give me your thoughts about solving this problem?

My solution:

X~ Binominal(1150,0.9) = Y ~ Normal(np,npq)

np= 1150*0.9 = 1035

npq= 1035*0.1= 103.5

P(X>1000)=1−P(X≤1000)≈1−P(Y<1000.5) = 1−P(Z<1000.5-1035/√103.5)=1−P(Z<-3.391)

= 1− [ 1- P(Z<3.391)] = 0.9997

So 99.97% that the hotel will not have enough space.

Comment: I'll look over it, but please use MathJaxx in the future, in makes the whole thing much more readable

Comment: Thank you so much, i will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mu = 1150\cdot 0.9 = 1035\\
\sigma^2 = 1150 \cdot (0.9)(0.1) = 103.5\\
\sigma = \sqrt {103.5} \approx 10$

we are looking for a $3\frac 12$ S.D. event.

$99.97\%$ sounds right.

Comment: Yes it also seems correct to me, although just using cumulated Binomial distribution would probably have been easier...

Comment: It depends what software is at your disposal.  The assumption of a normal distribution, and you can do this with no additional tools.